# Is it possible to build a scratch org with deliverability set to Email All? If so, how?

Tags: email, salesforcedx, scratch-org-definition-file

Just wondering if there is a feature or setting in the project definition that I can enable to have a scratch org with a Deliverability of 'Email All' or if that is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware, it's not possible. There's no such way to even set that setting in a Sandbox org aside from manual configuration in Setup, so I presume that the same is true for Scratch Orgs as well. It's one of the few things you'll need to set up manually.